# "May" implies choice...?

Tags: dos

> Single Color Match Bonus: at the end of your turn you may lay one card from your hand face-up in the Center Row.
>
> Double Color Match: at the end of your turn you (1) lay one card from your hand face-up in the Center Row and (2) all other players must draw one card from the Draw Pile.

**May I choose not to lay down a card for a Single Color Match?** *It might be better to end my turn with two cards instead of one, and the word "may" implies a decision; further, the word "may" is absent from the Double Color Match passage of the rules.*

Comment: In both English and common board game jargon, "you may do X" denotes that doing "X" is optional. Do you have any reason to believe otherwise here?

Comment: Well, I guess maybe I thought it was an oversight to use "may" on only one of the two rules. If that's intended, then it's only optional to lay the card on a single color match. I don't have any *good reason*, though. Also, I was not familiar with common board game jargon.

Comment: Ah yes,  good point

Comment: I would think that the use of may for one and not the other is intentional. This could be a way for them to balance out the strength of the bonuses.